# elasticsearch aggregate by multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm new to ElasticSearch, it looks awesome but I still need some paradigm-change to fully understand how to work with it.

**My project is a survey platform with a dashboard.**
A survey has multiple "screens" (questions) and each screen has multiple possible answers - a user chooses one and when he is done with the survey he submits it.

Let's say I have a document that looks like this (represents a survey that a user took):

```
{
    "survey_station_id": "199",
    "survey_id": "905",
    "survey_unique_identifier": "2016-05-11 08:45:34-e4c080d90264e47a1fdb2d021ca52d3a",
    "current_timestamp": 1462949134,
    "survey_timestamp": "1462949115",
    "answers": [{
        "screen_id": "9429",
        "answer_id": "4"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "9428",
        "answer_id": "3"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "9431",
        "answer_id": "0",
        "answer_text": "Very good"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "10819",
        "answer_id": "10742"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "10820",
        "answer_id": "0",
        "answer_text": "dan@somewhere.com"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "10821",
        "answer_id": "9"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "10822",
        "answer_id": "5"
    }, {
        "screen_id": "10823",
        "answer_id": "10745"
    }]
}
```

**I have tons of documents like this in my DB (or Index).**

In my dashboard, I want to show a breakdown by screen and count the number of each answer, something that will tell me this:

```
{
    screen_id: 9429,
    answers: [{
        answer_id: 1,
        doc_count: 150
    }, {
        answer_id: 2,
        doc_count: 23
    }],
    screen_id: 9428,
    answers: [{
        answer_id: 1,
        doc_count: 78
    }, {
        answer_id: 2,
        doc_count: 96
    }]
}
```

How can I accomplish that or similar? Is it possible and easy with my document structure or should I make some manipulations on it to improve the efficiency of such a requirement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to represent this data is one document per screen/answer including the survey id, timestamps, etc `{"screen_id":"10832", "answer_id":"10745", "survey_id": "905", "survey_timestamp": 1462949134, ...}`. It will be much easier to slice and dice the data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will think about it (It's really a good idea), but in general, if I want to accomplish such a requirement with my existing structure, is it possible?

Comment: You might be able to accomplish what you want but you need to make sure that `answers` is of type `nested` in your mapping.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example please?

Comment: The official documentation explains this pretty well [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Kibana (at the moment) does not support nested documents, but if you are building your own dashboard then I prefer nested solution to fully "flat" one. For example it makes it easier to calcualte statistics on just the root document and ignore screens when necessary.

Once you have sub-documents indexed as "nested" you need to have these elements in your aggregation query:

1. [Nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html)
2. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on `screen_id`
3. An other terms aggregation on `answer_id`

Be sure to set some sane limits on terms aggregations as otherwise you are likely encounter [combinatorial explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_preventing_combinatorial_explosions.html). Also note that you can have "include" and "exclude" rules on terms aggregation, if you are interested on only some of the screens. Actually I imagine you'll want to have a filter on `survey_id` as it doesn't make sense to aggregate results over different surveys (unless `screen_id`s are unique).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the comment made by @Val did the trick for me, I've read the corresponding parts of the documentation and managed to get to this solution. Nevertheless I will accept your answer for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, there are always trade-offs and assumptions on future queries when you decide the schema :) For example on flat schema it is difficult to calculate number of surveys taken / day. Oh actually it isn't, you can calculate cardinality of survey_unique_identifier, it just takes a bit more effort from ES and numbers aren't 100% accurate but very close.